# Mysql query convert into codeigniter active record

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, codeigniter-3

I have this query to convert into the Active record

```
SELECT (SELECT image FROM bc_item_image WHERE item_id = i.id LIMIT 1) as item_image, i.description, i.condition,c.cat_name as category_name,i.id as ID FROM bc_item i,bc_category c WHERE i.cat_id = c.id and i.user_id !='$user_id' and i.status = '1' and i.is_bartered = '0' and i.is_cancel = '0' and FIND_IN_SET('$subcat_id',i.interested_cat) order by i.display_count desc
```

Comment: use `$this->db->query()`

Comment: @AbdullaNilam i have used db->query() and it's work fine but can covert into the active record ?

Comment: I don't see a difference between those two. Both CI Built-in functions

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Okay thankyou for response.....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876763/codeigniter-this-db-query

Comment: it may help you https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$this->db->query('here your SQL query');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select(" i.description, i.condition,c.cat_name as category_name,i.id,(SELECT image FROM bc_item_image WHERE item_id = i.id LIMIT 1) as item_image");
$this->db->from('bc_item as i');
$this->db->join('bc_category as c', 'i.cat_id = c.id');
      $this->db->where('i.status', 1);
      $this->db->where('i.is_bartered', 0);
      $this->db->where('i.user_id','!=', $user_id);
      $this->db->where('i.is_cancel', 0);
      $this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('".$subcat_id."','i.interested_cat')");
      $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: it will return null

Comment: Same thing happen do not retrieve any data .. And i will solve my problem and i m using db->query().

Comment: @BhavyaSanchaniya ok